# Make one column fill remaining space in SlickGrid without messing up explicit width columns

Tags: slickgrid

Some of my columns need explicit widths, while others should just fill up all available space.

There is a forceFitColumns option, but it seems to ignore any explicit widths I've set.  I want my explicit widths to be respected, and for implicit ones to be estimated sanely.

I guess to get this behavior I'd have to disable the default column width and rewrite autoSizeColumns to not mess up my explicit column widths.  I can imagine a convention where you put in '*' for the column width if you'd like it to be auto-sized instead of using the default.  Has anyone made a fork that has this kind of feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "*" implicit width notation would be useful indeed.

Meanwhile, you can also set minWidth and maxWidth on your explicitly-sized columns so that they are not resized by forceFitColumns.

Comment: Ah I see.  If I set minWidth=maxWidth that would do the same thing as setting an explicit width, wouldn't it?  Thanks!